# How is Sandcastle possible to know the visibility of vs-project members

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle

i want to write my own html or xslt for C# Xml-Comments. I compile my Project with xml output, so i get a xml file with documentation. I understand the xml which visual studio generates up to one point. How is it possible to get the accessibilty of members. I know in Sandcastle (program to generate html from the c# xml documentation) is it possible to only use public members in documentation. But how can Sandcastle differ this?

For example a Method looks like this:

```
<member name="M:classes.myclass.mymethod">
 <summary>Some docu stuff</summary>
</member>
```

How can i see accessibility (private, internal, public etc.) or if its static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sandcastle generates documentation, it takes two inputs - the generated XML doc file and the compiled assembly (dll or exe). All the data that is not present in the XML file is gathered from the assembly using [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy).